# How to add picture in pygame menu?

Tags: python, selector, onchange, pygame-menu

I am working on a simple game on Python using module pygame.
I  made a menu, where user can choose a character for the game.

When the program is running, the names of the characters are displayed one by one, so user can choose a character for the game by using clicking, but I would also like to add a picture of the character himself under his name. I dont know how to do it, please help

Sorry for my English, I dont really good in it, but I hope you understand whats the problem.
Thanks a lot.

This is a part of my code with menu:

```
def set_hero(value, difficulty):
    global skin_h
    print(value, difficulty)
    if difficulty == 1:
        skin_h = 'images\чп.png'
    elif difficulty == 2:
        skin_h = 'images\iron man.png'
    elif difficulty == 3:
        skin_h = 'images\A usa man.png'
    elif difficulty == 4:
        skin_h = 'images\dead pool.png'


global skin_h
pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
mainmenu = pygame_menu.Menu('Welcome', 700, 700, theme=themes.THEME_SOLARIZED)
mainmenu.add.button('Choose your character  ', character_menu)
skin_h = 'images\чп.png'
skins_h = pygame_menu.Menu('Select a Character', 700, 700, theme=themes.THEME_BLUE)
skins_h.add.selector('Character :',
                 [('Spider man', 1), ('Iron man', 2), ('Captain America', 3), ('Dead Pool', 4)],
                 onchange=set_hero)
mainmenu.add.button('Play', start_the_game)
mainmenu.mainloop(surface)
```

I made a menu, so user can choose a character, but I cant put a picture of him under his name
I dont know how to add a picture in selector

Answer (score 0):

You have to first add an image widget and then, in the set_hero-method, change the image of it depending on the value of the selector. Take a look at these docs:

- [Add an image widget](https://pygame-menu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_source/add_widgets.html#add-an-image)
- [Change the image of an image widget](https://pygame-menu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_source/widgets_image.html#pygame_menu.widgets.Image.set_image)